# What can I use to create a Virtual Image from an existing linux installation?

Tags: virtualization, debian

I have a debian headless server that I need to migrate to run as a virtual server on Windows 2008.

What tools can I use to image the existing debian installation?

System I need to image:
Debian

Targeted host Platform:
Microsoft Hyper-V

Comment: Your question is incomplete and impossible to answer. Please include details of what type of virtual machine server you'll be using. (A less-important but still useful piece of info: What version of Debian?)

Comment: You should note that, Debian is not supported at all under Hyper-V (including no integrations). You might be better off considering going to ESXi. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although these instructions are written for VMware, they should work more-or-less for any type of virtual machine server

http://www.windley.com/archives/2007/08/p2v_how_to_make_a_physical_linux_box_into_a_virtual_machine.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) from the sysinternals guys.

Comment: Please read a little more carefully.

I have a debian linux machine.  Not windows

Comment: clarify this please? "migrate to run as a virtual server on Windows 2008" -- my uncareful reading took that to mean you are planning to move it a win2k8 hyper-v server.

Comment: really? A downvote for attempting to answer a somewhat vague question?